# How can I change the control source in Team Foundation Server 2018

Tags: windows, git, tfs

Could you please tell me, how I can change the control source in one project with TFS on Git? Thanks.

Comment: Thats not a programming question but just an IDE related one, and it would depend on the IDE used which no info is provided.

Comment: What do you mean by "change control source"?

Comment: I have a project. Version control -> Team Foundation Version Control. I want to change  Version control on git.

Answer (score 0):

You may do next:

1. [Import repositories from TFVC to Git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/import-from-tfvc?view=vsts)

OR

1. Create git repository [Create a new Git repo in your project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/create-new-repo?view=vsts)
2. Clone your [git repository Clone an existing Git repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/tutorial/clone?view=vsts&tabs=visual-studio)
3. Copy&past you VS soulution to new location
4. Unbind existing source control [How to Completely Remove TFS Source Control Bindings](https://theprogressiveviews.blogspot.com/2016/01/how-to-completely-remove-tfs-source.html#!/2016/01/how-to-completely-remove-tfs-source.html)
5. Check current source control provider on VS options:
   [image]
6. Work with your solution [Get Started with Git and VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/gitquickstart?view=vsts&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Thank you Aleksander, I still have a small question.What's the difference from local storage git and local workspace TFS.

Comment: That is not a small question )) But you can find useful information here: [Choosing the right version control for your project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/comparison-git-tfvc?view=vsts) and [Team Foundation Version Control Verses Git in Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.petri.com/team-foundation-version-control-verses-git-visual-studio-team-services)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean migrate or convert TFVC to Git, then you can use the tool [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs). It's a two-way bridge between TFS (Team Foundation Server) and git, similar to git-svn. It fetches TFS commits into a git repository, and lets you push your updates back to TFS.

However the easiest way is [importing repositories from TFVC to Git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/import-from-tfvc?view=vsts) in TFS 2018